# Unity3d + WebGL = Cross-Origin Request Blocked

Tags: unity-game-engine, parse-platform, cors

I was wondering if anyone could briefly explain how you get the REST api to function with Unity3D project built to WebGL platform. I just started changing my project over today thinking I could use REST to get around Parse's use of threading in a WebGL build I need to make. I promptly ran into the CORS problem though and not being familiar with it, I am unsure how to go about fixing the issue.

Currently I make use of the WWW class to send the request from within Unity.

An Example of "Logging In" a user would be:

```
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();

        var headers = form.headers;
        headers["Method"] = "GET";
        headers["X-Parse-Application-Id"] = AppID;
        headers["X-Parse-REST-API-Key"] = RestID;
        headers["X-Parse-Revocable-Session"] = "1";
        headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";

        WWW www = new WWW("https://api.parse.com/1/login?username="+name+"&password="+password, null, headers);
```

This works fine in the Editor but after building to WEBGL and uploading to my Host at Parse the following happens...

I receive the following error in FireFox:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.parse.com/1/login?username=jleslie5159&password=Osulator5159!. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

And something similar in Chrome...

Comment: Send it as a POST request and see if it changes things for you.

Comment: Gave it a try, didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Sorry! According to the documentation, Unity is set up for it.  http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-networking.html I'd ask on the parse.com google group to understand why this isn't working.

Comment: One other thing you might try is to specify the encoding.

Comment: Such as headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json; charset=utf-8"

Comment: I'm searching for an answer there as well. I found in on the Parse website a mention that they set CORS up for the javascript SDK... maybe its not configured to work with the REST API. Yet I found a post on the Google Group by a dev saying they had gotten it to work, but no explanation so I'm not sure.

Comment: From the Parse Google Group: "We used Unity's WWW / coroutine system with the X-Parse-[...] headers for the REST API (required because the Unity API doesn't expose cross-origin access to Chrome when Unity WebGL pipes web requests through the browser), then we built a wrapper around parse objects to handle JSON serialization / deserialization and also to track objectId / session tokens for users. The REST API exposes everything we need for our purposes, so it's just a matter of mapping the right endpoints / parsing the data correctly."

Comment: Yeah, I'm tapped on info. My next suggestion would be to switch to something like PHP and setup your own domain communication to parse.com on the server side. :( Sorry I wasn't more help.

Comment: I don't know much about web development per se, but wouldn't you get the same error if you just put an empty page (without unity plugin) there that would try to launch this request with javascript?

Comment: According to this (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), your request may be perceived as a preflighted one, because of `headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";`. Have you tried setting it to plain text instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else looking I solved my problem like so:

```
WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        var headers = form.headers;
        headers["X-Parse-Application-Id"] = "AppId";
        headers["X-Parse-REST-API-Key"] = "RestKey";
        headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
        WWW www = new WWW("https://api.parse.com/1/login?username="+name+"&password="+password, null, headers);
        while(!www.isDone)
            yield return 1;
```

The problem stemmed from setting the "headers["Method"] = "GET""  Apparently only certain headers are allowed to be sent or you trigger a CORS violation. I solved the problem by reading the response in the browser console which specified why the request was blocked. And just removed the offending Headers.

Answer (score 0):

I solve by adding header **Access-Control-Allow-Origin:***  in response from server.

nginx.conf

```
location / {
  server_name example.xyz;
  listen 8080;
  
...
...
  
  # Enable CORS
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;

...
...

}
```

For the explanation, you can figure it out from this link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Hope this help :)

Comment: The link no longer works. Could you update the link or explain more how this is done? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @TheOddler Sorry, I'm not the above link's owner. But I found this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) which use the same idea. 
it's better for you to set in server config as [link](http://enable-cors.org/server.html)
or try this in NodeJS `response.writeHead(200, {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'});`

Comment: i dont understand why you dont just give the solution? why send us to other links if you have figured it out?

Comment: @loekTheDreamer Thank you for your comment. I agree with you and added the example to the answer.