# Why does unity show question mark instead of desired sprite?

Tags: c#, html, unity-game-engine, web, sprite

In unity3d, I am using WWW class to download a texture from link, then I am creating a Sprite with the obtained texture and I am displaying it on the screen. This is working just fine in Unity Editor, but when I run it in the browser as HTML5 instead of displaying my Sprite, there is a red question mark. Why?

This is my C# code:

```
GameObject myImage;
Sprite neededSprite;

IEnumerator Start () {

 WWW getMyImage= new WWW("http://previews.123rf.com/images/burakowski/burakowski1202/burakowski120200228/12221967-Grunge-Example-stamp-Stock-Vector-demo.jpg");

 myImage = GameObject.Find("myImage");

 yield return getMyImage;
 Texture2D rawImage = getMyImage.texture;
 neededSprite = Sprite.Create(rawImage, new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, rawImage.width, rawImage.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 100.0f);
 myImage.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = neededSprite;

}
```

Comment: Have you got any error in your browser console ? I suspect a cross-origin problem : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-networking.html

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30090907/unity3d-webgl-cross-origin-request-blocked

Comment: Try saving the downloaded texture as png to see if it is a valid texture. Use [`Texture2D.EncodeToPNG`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.EncodeToPNG.html)

Comment: It is a cross-origin problem, just like @Hellium said. I know how to solve it for a url with a string content. I put in the php file `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` How do I apply this for a `.jpg` file? How do I allow access on a server to obtain an image?

Comment: Here is a nice website to learn how to deal with CORS : http://enable-cors.org. If the server is an Apach, the easiest way is to put a htaccess with specific instructions next to the resources you are trying to get

Comment: Thanks @Hellium, you helped a lot!

Comment: After placing `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` in `.htaccess` file, everything is working as excepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After placing `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` in `.htaccess` file, everything is working as excepted