# Unity3D WebGL Build can't communicate via UnityWebRequest

Tags: unity-game-engine, http-headers, webgl

```cs
//...
    const string webURL = "http://dreamlo.com/lb/";

    IEnumerator UploadNewHighscore(string username, int score) {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        
        using (UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Post(webURL + privateCode + "/add/" + UnityWebRequest.EscapeURL(username) + "/" + score, form)) {
            
            request.SetRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            
            request.SetRequestHeader("Method", "POST");
            
            yield return request.SendWebRequest();
            
            if (request.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
                Debug.Log("Error Uploading: " + request.error);
            else
                print("Upload successful!!");
        }
        
    }
    
    IEnumerator DownloadHighscoresFromDB() {     
        loadingText.gameObject.SetActive(true); // enable loading text
        
        using (UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Get(webURL + publicCode + "/pipe/" + maxScoresNumber)) {
            
            request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
            
            request.SetRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            
            request.SetRequestHeader("Method", "GET");
            
            yield return request.SendWebRequest();
            
            List<string> formattedStrings = new List<string>();
            
            if (request.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
                Debug.Log("Error downloading: " + request.error);
            else
                print("Download Success.");
                PublicFormatHighScores(request.downloadHandler.text);
                
                if (onScoresDownloaded != null) // [B] Broadcast that scores have been downloaded
                    onScoresDownloaded();
                    loadingText.gameObject.SetActive(false); // remove loading text
        }
//...
```

Once a player dies in the game, scores are grabbed via a dreamlo.com rest api. After building to webgl and hosting on various platforms, the same error occurs. I've tried hosting to play.unity.com, gamejolt, and building&running to a local server. The errors in the browser developer console that prevent requests from being sent are:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource a at https://dreamlo.com/lb/###redactedapikey###/pipe/9 (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://dreamlo.com/lb/###redactedapikey###/pipe/9. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

In the network tab of the developer tools, I should note that this error appears when inspecting the header status. The failed GET status has no returned header data:
[image]

In the code example, I've tried to set the headers of the requests to have the proper method and access controller as recommended in this post ([Unity3d + WebGL = Cross-Origin Request Blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30090907/unity3d-webgl-cross-origin-request-blocked)), however to no avail. I've also tried altering the access method permissions by adding the line `request.SetRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS");`. I've also tried to instead of using wild card `*`, setting the request header to each url I want to be able to communicate with (recommended by [CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' does not match... but it does‼](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35303654/cors-header-access-control-allow-origin-does-not-match-but-it-does)). In the case of hosting with play.unity, this would be

```
request.SetRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://play.unity.com");
request.SetRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://dreamlo.com");
request.SetRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://dreamlo.com");
```

I've also tried adding these urls as csvs, with the line `request.SetRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://play.unity.com,http://dreamlo.com,https://dreamlo.com");`

**None** of these methods have worked.

I've seen in a couple forum posts on various sites that the server itself may need to be configured to allow cross origin requests, however I wish to host on sites that don't allow the user to edit these configurations.

Comment: Have you tried to specify the other headers mentioned in [Networking in WebGL](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/webgl-networking.html) .. problem: It also has to be supported **server side**! Otherwise it won't work

Comment: Yeah, it seems I must either host my own server where I configure COR settings or give the user a proper platform error message.